# API Python connection error occurrence, [SSL socket programming inquiry]

Tags: ssl

An SSL handshake error occurred in the process of making an API call with Python.

The reason for the SSL handshake error is that information such as client certificate, CA certificate, and client private key should be used as options.

Query curl -k --tlsv1.2 --cacert ./ca-chain.crt --cert ./client.crt --key ./client.key -H
You should have the above settings.

I found the tlsv1.2 part at the beginning through an internet search,

import ssl
I learned that I just need to add the syntax context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2) .

Then cacert ./ca-chain.crt --cert ./client.crt --key ./client.key did not know how to implement this part in Python code, so I asked a question.

The client certificate, CA certificate, and client private key are in the state that I extracted and kept with openssl.

Query: curl -k --tlsv1.2 --cacert ./ca-chain.crt --cert ./client.crt --key ./client.key -H I would like to know how to implement this in python code.

Thanks for reading this long post.

Answer (score 0):

> Then cacert ./ca-chain.crt --cert ./client.crt --key ./client.key did not know how to implement this part in Python code, so I asked a question.

```
ctx.load_verify_locations('./ca-chain.crt')
ctx.load_cert_chain('./client.crt', './client.key')
```

For more see [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html).